# Advertisements not removed after IAP unless app is restarted?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, storekit

In my app, there is code that, if a button is pressed the user can upgrade the app and remove the advertisements, it calls the MKStoreKit and once the user purchases the upgrade, the adverts do remain in the app UNTIL the app is restarted.

I want to fix this, so the advertisements are removed immediately, but how would I go about doing this?

Here is some of the code;

```
-(IBAction)removeAds:(id)sender
{

    if (![MKStoreManager isFeaturePurchased:@"com.davidsapps.puzzler.removeads"]) { //

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Upgrade App" message:@"To upgrade and remove all advertisements from this app Please click OK to purchase the upgrade!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No Thanks" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes Please",nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }

}
```

The alert it links to;

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0){
        //cancel button clicked. Do something here or nothing here
    }
    else{
        //other button indexes clicked
        [[MKStoreManager sharedManager] buyFeature:@- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0){
        //cancel button clicked. Do something here or nothing here
    }
    else{
        //other button indexes clicked
        [[MKStoreManager sharedManager] buyFeature:@"com.idevver.mybatterypal.upgrade"];
    }
    }
}
```

Using MKStoreKit

Is there anything I can do to make it remove the advertisements without the user having to restart the app?

Thanks,

Chris

EDIT - the advertisements are Admob Mediation, using this code in the ViewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {


        bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait];
        bannerView_.adUnitID = MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID;
        CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
        CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
        CGFloat screenXPos = (screenWidth /2);
        CGFloat screenYPos = screenHeight - 90;
        [bannerView_ setCenter:CGPointMake(screenXPos, screenYPos)];
        bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
        bannerView_.adUnitID = MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID;
        bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
        [self.view addSubview:bannerView_];
```

This is the code that actually calls the advertisement banner, it is in an if/else statement later in the viewDidLoad

```
if (![MKStoreManager isFeaturePurchased:@"com.davidsapps.puzzler.removeads"]) { //


        [bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
    }
```

So I guess somehow when the feature is purchased, I need to add to the MKStoreManager.m file something to say dismiss the bannerView_ code above?

Would that work?

EDIT 2  - Full .m file for the in-app code (with thanks to MugunthKumar for a wonderful kit)

```
//
//  MKStoreManager.m
//  MKStoreKit
//
//  Created by Mugunth Kumar on 17-Nov-2010.
//  Copyright 2010 Steinlogic. All rights reserved.
//  File created using Singleton XCode Template by Mugunth Kumar (http://mugunthkumar.com
//  Permission granted to do anything, commercial/non-commercial with this file apart from removing the line/URL above
//  Read my blog post at http://mk.sg/1m on how to use this code

//  As a side note on using this code, you might consider giving some credit to me by
//  1) linking my website from your app's website 
//  2) or crediting me inside the app's credits page 
//  3) or a tweet mentioning @mugunthkumar
//  4) A paypal donation to mugunth.kumar@gmail.com
//
//  A note on redistribution
//  While I'm ok with modifications to this source code, 
//  if you are re-publishing after editing, please retain the above copyright notices

#import "MKStoreManager.h"
#import "GADBannerView.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface MKStoreManager (PrivateMethods)

- (void) requestProductData;
- (BOOL) canCurrentDeviceUseFeature: (NSString*) featureID;
- (BOOL) verifyReceipt:(NSData*) receiptData;
- (void) enableContentForThisSession: (NSString*) productIdentifier;

@end

@implementation MKStoreManager

@synthesize purchasableObjects = _purchasableObjects;
@synthesize storeObserver = _storeObserver;

static NSString *ownServer = nil;

static __weak id<MKStoreKitDelegate> _delegate;
static MKStoreManager* _sharedStoreManager;


- (void)dealloc {

    [_purchasableObjects release];
    [_storeObserver release];

    [_sharedStoreManager release];
    [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark Delegates

+ (id)delegate {

    return _delegate;
}

+ (void)setDelegate:(id)newDelegate {

    _delegate = newDelegate;    
}

#pragma mark Singleton Methods

+ (MKStoreManager*)sharedManager
{
    @synchronized(self) {

        if (_sharedStoreManager == nil) {

#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
            NSLog(@"You are running in Simulator MKStoreKit runs only on devices");
#else
            _sharedStoreManager = [[self alloc] init];                  
            _sharedStoreManager.purchasableObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            [_sharedStoreManager requestProductData];                       
            _sharedStoreManager.storeObserver = [[MKStoreObserver alloc] init];
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:_sharedStoreManager.storeObserver];           
#endif
        }
    }
    return _sharedStoreManager;
}


+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone

{   
    @synchronized(self) {

        if (_sharedStoreManager == nil) {

            _sharedStoreManager = [super allocWithZone:zone];           
            return _sharedStoreManager;  // assignment and return on first allocation
        }
    }

    return nil; //on subsequent allocation attempts return nil  
}


- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    return self;    
}

- (id)retain
{   
    return self;    
}

- (unsigned)retainCount
{
    return UINT_MAX;  //denotes an object that cannot be released
}

- (void)release
{
    //do nothing
}

- (id)autorelease
{
    return self;    
}

#pragma mark Internal MKStoreKit functions

- (void) restorePreviousTransactions
{
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}

-(void) requestProductData
{
    SKProductsRequest *request= [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObjects: 
                                  kFeatureAId,
                                  kConsumableFeatureBId,
                                  kConsumableBaseFeatureId,
                                  nil]];
    request.delegate = self;
    [request start];
}

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    [self.purchasableObjects addObjectsFromArray:response.products];

#ifndef NDEBUG  
    for(int i=0;i<[self.purchasableObjects count];i++)
    {       
        SKProduct *product = [self.purchasableObjects objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"Feature: %@, Cost: %f, ID: %@",[product localizedTitle],
              [[product price] doubleValue], [product productIdentifier]);
    }

    for(NSString *invalidProduct in response.invalidProductIdentifiers)
        NSLog(@"Problem in iTunes connect configuration for product: %@", invalidProduct);
#endif

    [request autorelease];

    isProductsAvailable = YES;

    if([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(productFetchComplete)])
        [_delegate productFetchComplete];   
}


// call this function to check if the user has already purchased your feature
+ (BOOL) isFeaturePurchased:(NSString*) featureId
{


    return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:featureId];

}

// Call this function to populate your UI
// this function automatically formats the currency based on the user's locale

- (NSMutableArray*) purchasableObjectsDescription
{
    NSMutableArray *productDescriptions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[self.purchasableObjects count]];
    for(int i=0;i<[self.purchasableObjects count];i++)
    {
        SKProduct *product = [self.purchasableObjects objectAtIndex:i];

        NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        [numberFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
        [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
        [numberFormatter setLocale:product.priceLocale];
        NSString *formattedString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:product.price];
        [numberFormatter release];

        // you might probably need to change this line to suit your UI needs
        NSString *description = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (%@)",[product localizedTitle], formattedString];

#ifndef NDEBUG
        NSLog(@"Product %d - %@", i, description);
#endif
        [productDescriptions addObject: description];
    }

    [productDescriptions autorelease];
    return productDescriptions;
}


- (void) buyFeature:(NSString*) featureId
{


    if([self canCurrentDeviceUseFeature: featureId])
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Review request approved", @"")
                                                        message:NSLocalizedString(@"You can use this feature for reviewing the app.", @"")
                                                       delegate:self 
                                              cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Dismiss", @"")
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];

        [self enableContentForThisSession:featureId];
        return;
    }

    if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments])
    {
        SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:featureId];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"In-App Purchasing disabled", @"")
                                                        message:NSLocalizedString(@"Check your parental control settings and try again later", @"")
                                                       delegate:self 
                                              cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Dismiss", @"")
                                              otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];

    }
}

- (BOOL) canConsumeProduct:(NSString*) productIdentifier
{
    int count = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:productIdentifier];

    return (count > 0);

}

- (BOOL) canConsumeProduct:(NSString*) productIdentifier quantity:(int) quantity
{
    int count = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:productIdentifier];
    return (count >= quantity);
}

- (BOOL) consumeProduct:(NSString*) productIdentifier quantity:(int) quantity
{
    int count = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:productIdentifier];
    if(count < quantity)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    else 
    {
        count -= quantity;
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:count forKey:productIdentifier];
        return YES;
    }

}

-(void) enableContentForThisSession: (NSString*) productIdentifier
{
    if([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(productPurchased:)])
        [_delegate productPurchased:productIdentifier];

}


#pragma mark In-App purchases callbacks
// In most cases you don't have to touch these methods
-(void) provideContent: (NSString*) productIdentifier 
           forReceipt:(NSData*) receiptData
{
    if(ownServer != nil && SERVER_PRODUCT_MODEL)
    {
        // ping server and get response before serializing the product
        // this is a blocking call to post receipt data to your server
        // it should normally take a couple of seconds on a good 3G connection
        if(![self verifyReceipt:receiptData]) return;
    }

    NSRange range = [productIdentifier rangeOfString:kConsumableBaseFeatureId];     
    NSString *countText = [productIdentifier substringFromIndex:range.location+[kConsumableBaseFeatureId length]];

    int quantityPurchased = [countText intValue];
    if(quantityPurchased != 0)
    {

        int oldCount = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:productIdentifier];
        oldCount += quantityPurchased;  

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:oldCount forKey:productIdentifier];       
    }
    else 
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:productIdentifier];       
    }

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    if([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(productPurchased:)])
        [_delegate productPurchased:productIdentifier];

UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"In-App Upgrade" message:@"Successfull removal of advertisements upgrade - thankyou" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

[alert show];
[alert release];

}

- (void) transactionCanceled: (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{

#ifndef NDEBUG
    NSLog(@"User cancelled transaction: %@", [transaction description]);
#endif

    if([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(transactionCanceled)])
        [_delegate transactionCanceled];
}

- (void) failedTransaction: (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[transaction.error localizedFailureReason] 
                                                    message:[transaction.error localizedRecoverySuggestion]
                                                   delegate:self 
                                          cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Dismiss", @"")
                                          otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}



#pragma mark In-App purchases promo codes support
// This function is only used if you want to enable in-app purchases for free for reviewers
// Read my blog post http://mk.sg/31
- (BOOL) canCurrentDeviceUseFeature: (NSString*) featureID
{
    NSString *uniqueID = [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];
    // check udid and featureid with developer's server

    if(ownServer == nil) return NO; // sanity check

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", ownServer, @"featureCheck.php"]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url 
                                                              cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData 
                                                          timeoutInterval:60];

    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];     
    [theRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSString *postData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"productid=%@&udid=%@", featureID, uniqueID];

    NSString *length = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];    
    [theRequest setValue:length forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];  

    [theRequest setHTTPBody:[postData dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

    NSHTTPURLResponse* urlResponse = nil;
    NSError *error = [[[NSError alloc] init] autorelease];  

    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest
                                                 returningResponse:&urlResponse 
                                                             error:&error];  

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    BOOL retVal = NO;
    if([responseString isEqualToString:@"YES"])     
    {
        retVal = YES;
    }

    [responseString release];
    return retVal;
}

// This function is only used if you want to enable in-app purchases for free for reviewers
// Read my blog post http://mk.sg/

-(BOOL) verifyReceipt:(NSData*) receiptData
{
    if(ownServer == nil) return NO; // sanity check

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", ownServer, @"verifyProduct.php"]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url 
                                                              cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData 
                                                          timeoutInterval:60];

    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];     
    [theRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSString *receiptDataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receiptData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSString *postData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"receiptdata=%@", receiptDataString];
    [receiptDataString release];

    NSString *length = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];    
    [theRequest setValue:length forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];  

    [theRequest setHTTPBody:[postData dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

    NSHTTPURLResponse* urlResponse = nil;
    NSError *error = [[[NSError alloc] init] autorelease];  

    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest
                                                 returningResponse:&urlResponse 
                                                             error:&error];  

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    BOOL retVal = NO;
    if([responseString isEqualToString:@"YES"])     
    {
        retVal = YES;
    }

    [responseString release];
    return retVal;
}
@end
```

Comment: You might have to add some code regarding how you display your ads. Are you using iAds, AdMob, etc?

Comment: Hi Joe - I updated original question to show some advert code I use :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the purchase completes, it is up to you to remove the ads. Do something similar to this.

```
[bannerView removeFromSuperview];
```

All you have to do is hide the ads when the purchase completes.

Comment: Hi, the advertisement code, is just using Admob Mediation, I just load the GAD Banner view, I have added it to my original question, the code that is added to the ViewDidLoad I have updated my question hopefully this helps :)

Comment: Hi Jack, whereabouts would I put that though, as if I put that on the removeAds IBAction then all that happens, is when the user presses that button, even if they dismiss the alert, the banner disappears without them needing to purchase? Kind regards, Chris.

Comment: Oh, I understand. Do you know how to check for when an in app purchase completes?

Comment: Unfortunately not :( I figured it might be in the MKStoreManager.m code though? There are plenty of things in there such as buyFeature etc etc?

Comment: Can you point me to where you found this in app purchase code? I might be able to figure out where you should put the code I gave you above. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Jack, it's just MKStoreKit code which is
http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/introducing-mkstorekit-%E2%80%93-version-3/

Comment: Hi Jack, thats the MKStoreKit 5, I use an earlier version, I have pasted the entire code from the .m file of the storekit file I use, let me know if that one is easier to check?

Comment: Do you see the alert view with the message, "Successful removal of advertisements upgrade..." Place the code right there.

Comment: Strange, I added; [bannerView_ removeFromSuperview];

To that part, but it still does not dismiss the view when the purchase completes :(

Comment: The alert view ("Successful removal of...") definitely appears when the purchase completes, right? I just want to make sure that the code is definitely being executed. If it is, then try `bannerView_.hidden = YES;`.

Comment: Yeah it definitely shows when the purchase is completed, but the bannerview still shows, even when trying bannerView_.hidden = YES;

Should that be before the UIAlert, during or after??